# How to generate both server and client certificates under root CA

Tags: python, bash, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

So, I've been trying to set up an SSL connection between a python client and python server in which both have separate certificates to validate each-other, and both certificates are signed by one CA (which also happens to be the root CA). This should make them both valid to each-other, correct?

My methodology thus far has been to create a bash script that does it all:

1. It generates the private key for the Root CA
2. It generates the Root CA cert using the Root CA private key
3. It generates the private key for the server
4. It generates the CSR for the server
5. It generates the server Cert using the server CSR and Root CA cert
6. It generates the private key for the client
7. It generates the CSR for the client
8. It generates the client Cert using the client CSR and Root CA cert

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BOLD=$(tput bold)
CLEAR=$(tput sgr0)

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating RSA AES-256 Private Key for Root Certificate Authority${CLEAR}"
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out Root.CA.example.llc.key 4096

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate for Root Certificate Authority${CLEAR}"
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key Root.CA.example.llc.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out Root.CA.example.llc.pem

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating RSA Private Key for Server Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl genrsa -out server/example.llc.server.key 4096

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate Signing Request for Server Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl req -new -key server/example.llc.server.key -out server/example.llc.server.csr

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate for Server Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl x509 -req -in server/example.llc.server.csr -CA Root.CA.example.llc.pem -CAkey Root.CA.example.llc.key -CAcreateserial -out server/example.llc.server.crt -days 1825 -sha256 -extfile server/example.llc.server.ext

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating RSA Private Key for Client Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl genrsa -out client/example.llc.client.key 4096

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate Signing Request for Client Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl req -new -key client/example.llc.client.key -out client/example.llc.client.csr

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate for Client Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl x509 -req -days 1825 -in client/example.llc.client.csr -CA Root.CA.example.llc.pem -CAkey Root.CA.example.llc.key -set_serial 01 -out client/example.llc.client.crt

echo "Done!"
```

The server loads these credentials:

```py
cntx = SSL.Context(...)
# ...
cntx.use_privatekey_file('example.llc.server.key')
cntx.use_certificate_file('example.llc.server.cert')
cntx.load_verify_locations('../Root.CA.example.llc.pem')
```

The client loads these credentials:

```py
cntx = SSL.Context(...)
# ...
cntx.use_privatekey_file('example.llc.client.key')
cntx.use_certificate_file('example.llc.client.cert')
cntx.load_verify_locations('../Root.CA.example.llc.pem')
```

The server launches like a rocket

```py
server = SSL.Connection(cntx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
server.bind(('localhost', 44000))
server.listen(1)
server.setblocking(1)
cli, addr = server.accept()
```

and the client attempts to connect with

```py
SSL.Connection(cntx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
sock.connect(('localhost', 44000))
```

then I get hit with this madness:

```py
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca')]
```

At this point, I'm not sure if the client and server certs should be signed by the root CA, if the client cert should be signed by the server cert, or if I'm going insane with all this certificate trust chain SSL/TLS magic wizard voodoo craziness. Please help.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with your code. But to answer your last question - both client and server certs should be signed by the CA which is what you appear to be doing. How about testing SSL with just the server cert first and then the client so you know which cert is causing the issue.

Comment: Wow! Good call! It turns out my client cert generation code is wrong. It is self-signing the certificate instead of using the CSR and Root CA to sign itself. I got an error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate. I'll edit and re-test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

And that's all she wrote!

Steve E. pointed out that the certs needed to be verified and so the culprit was found to be the self-signed client cert.

```bash
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile Root.CA.example.llc.pem server/example.llc.server.crt
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile Root.CA.example.llc.pem client/example.llc.client.crt
```

Here's the new autogen code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BOLD=$(tput bold)
CLEAR=$(tput sgr0)

iterate=(server/ client/)
for dir in "${iterate[@]}"; do
  [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir -p "$dir" \
  && echo -e "${BOLD}directory '$dir' was created ${CLEAR}"
done

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating RSA AES-256 Private Key for Root Certificate Authority${CLEAR}"
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out Root.CA.example.llc.key 4096

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate for Root Certificate Authority${CLEAR}"
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key Root.CA.example.llc.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out Root.CA.example.llc.pem

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating RSA Private Key for Server Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl genrsa -out server/example.llc.server.key 4096

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate Signing Request for Server Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl req -new -key server/example.llc.server.key -out server/example.llc.server.csr

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate for Server Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl x509 -req -in server/example.llc.server.csr -CA Root.CA.example.llc.pem -CAkey Root.CA.example.llc.key -CAcreateserial -out server/example.llc.server.crt -days 1825 -sha256 -extfile server/example.llc.server.ext

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating RSA Private Key for Client Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl genrsa -out client/example.llc.client.key 4096

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate Signing Request for Client Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl req -new -key client/example.llc.client.key -out client/example.llc.client.csr

echo -e "${BOLD}Generating Certificate for Client Certificate${CLEAR}"
openssl x509 -req -in client/example.llc.client.csr -CA Root.CA.example.llc.pem -CAkey Root.CA.example.llc.key -CAcreateserial -out client/example.llc.client.crt -days 1825 -sha256

echo "Done!"
```

Good luck and godspeed to anyone who is trying to create a self-signed root CA with double-sided authentication for client/server systems!